# Is there a dashboard widget that has extended Unicode characters?

Tags: dashboard-widget, dashboard, unicode

I've been looking for a decent Unicode widget that allows access to some of the weirder characters like ✓ and ✗.

Does such a beast exist? I've tried a few and all of them seem kind of limited... Also, Apple's built-in character viewer doesn't indicate anything like HTML escape code or even Unicode number, I'd use that otherwise.

These ones I've tried:

- [Characterpal](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/reference/characterpal.html)
- [Entitiy lookup](http://leftlogic.com/projects/entity-lookup)
- [Asciitable](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/developer/asciitable.html)

Comment: Most people would use the Character Viewer for this.  Is there a reason that does not meet your needs?

Comment: @TomGewecke -- Biggest reason is that it doesn't list HTML escape codes.

Comment: But general html escape codes are just the unicode hex number from Character Viewer inside &#x and ;.  You might also find the app Unicode Checker useful.

Comment: PS When composing html it is normally much better to use the real characters and utf-8 encoding instead of escape sequences intended for the 1990's when everything was in ascii.

Comment: Character Viewer doesn't even show code points by default anymore. They are shown in the sidebar if you enable the Unicode category though.

Comment: @LauriRanta -- Oh wow! I didn't even realize there was a Unicode table in Character Viewer -- It's under the gear icon, "Customize List...", Code Tables, Unicode. Thanks!

Comment: @TomGewecke -- That's interesting re: just using the real character; could you elaborate on that?

Comment: To input the real character you just copy/paste (or double click on it in Character Viewer) to insert it into your html code and make sure you have a charset=utf-8 meta statement at the top.

Comment: @TomGewecke -- I was meaning more in terms of it being "better" to use the real characters instead of the escape code. Any reason for that?

Comment: The main reason is that escape codes in general are not legible by humans who have not memorized them, so that it makes editing of source code much more difficult.  Also perhaps just the fact that it represents a technique intended for a much earlier stage of ascii-only web technology and thus might mark the site author as not very up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find one, unfortunately. If you know the codes (which you can easily find from the web) you can enable the Unicode Hex input from System Preferences>Language and Text>Input Sources (it's near the bottom). That way, when you hold ALT, you can enter a Unicode symbol number for that symbol to appear.

Example: ALT+270E enters a ✎ pencil.